# Expo package APK / IPA package is too large

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Now we use exp cli (because we want to be compatible with the Expo development adopted by Android IOS WEB), but `Expo build:android` Or `Expo build:ios` The bag will be very big

According to some data, `react native` has been set to the form of outer chain, but the weight of the package itself has not been reduced

How can I reduce APK / IPA volume

Comment: The expo team cover this quite extensively in their documentation: https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/master/managed-app-size.md. Short answer, if a small app size is a requirement, expo probably isn't for you unless you go for the bare workflow.

Comment: If I use bare workflow, should I execute the `npm run eject` command?

Comment: By using eject, you will be using the bare workflow yes.

Comment: ok Thanks for you